# JavaScript: не удаляется обработчик события

Tags: javascript

В следующем коде я вешаю обработчик события. Затем хочу его удалить, но он почему-то не удаляется. Не могу понять почему.

```js
function DataLoaderWhenPageAtBottom() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this._whenPageAtBottom);
};

DataLoaderWhenPageAtBottom.prototype._whenPageAtBottom = function() {
  // Здесь у нас `this` есть `window`.
  var html = document.documentElement;
  var body = document.body;
  if (
    window.innerHeight + window.scrollY
    >=
    Math.max(
      body.scrollHeight, html.scrollHeight,
      body.offsetHeight, html.offsetHeight,
      body.clientHeight, html.clientHeight
    )
  ) {
    window.removeEventListener(
      'scroll', DataLoaderWhenPageAtBottom._whenPageAtBottom
    );
    console.log('At bottom!');
  }
};

new DataLoaderWhenPageAtBottom();
```

```html
<div style="height: 1000px;"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pmqhb8s1/

---

Я также пробовал связать добавляемую функцию с `this`. То есть при назначении обработчика делал так:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', this._whenPageAtBottom.bind(this))
```

А при удалении так:

```
window.removeEventListener('scroll', this._whenPageAtBottom);
```

Но, как вы понимаете, это тоже не помогло.

Что-то где-то я не знаю или не досмотрел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DataLoaderWhenPageAtBottom._whenPageAtBottom - undefined
DataLoaderWhenPageAtBottom.prototype._whenPageAtBottom - defined
```

Comment: Емае. Блин! Как же вы правы.

Comment: @RomanGrinyov , т.е. вы разобрались? добавьте рабочее решение пожалуйста

Comment: @stas0k, да, просто нужно не `window.removeEventListener('scroll', DataLoaderWhenPageAtBottom._whenPageAtBottom);`, а `window.removeEventListener('scroll', DataLoaderWhenPageAtBottom.prototype._whenPageAtBottom);`. https://jsfiddle.net/ed5w8ca8/